# Restricting access to Glue Jobs and Crawlers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

So, as per the AWS documenation (and confirmed through some testing and tweaking with IAM policies), there is no way to control access to running Glue Jobs or Crawlers, either via resource-based authorization (using ARNs) or tag-based (using resource tags). In a nutshell: if you give some entity access to `glue:StartJobRun` for instance, this will give access to run ALL and ANY jobs it wants. Pretty weird, right?

I need ideas for achieving access control outside Glue. I thought of Lambda, but it doesn't really work because the Lambda function can't really "know" who called it in order to check some parameters like Principal tags and compare it to the accessed resources.

Also, the solution should not be too cumbersome to the user, as I'm removing his ability to easily run stuff with the console to somewhere else. I can't really force him to go through several complicated steps to achieve something as simple as running his own job.

Thoughts?